# cmake seems to not pick up my -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS

Tags: command-line, cmake, command-line-arguments, include-path

I have a totally simple setup. Two files in two separate directories.

```
mkdir a
touch a/a.h
mkdir b
echo '#include <a/a.h>' > b/b.c
```

Compiling works, when I specify a header path

```
cd b
gcc -c -I.. b.c
cd ..
```

OK now let's add **cmake** to the picture. For my purposes I need to specify the header search path via the command-line. Consider the CMakeLists.txt read only.

```
cat<<EOF > b/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)

project (b)

add_library(b
b.c
)
EOF


mkdir b/build
cd b/build
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I.. ..
make VERBOSE=1
```

But make fails and I don't see the **-I..** specification in the `cc` command line.

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains    /XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.c.o   -c /tmp/b/b.c
/tmp/b/b.c:1:10: fatal error: 'a/a.h' file not found
```

I tried giving an absolute path too, but it just doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has `.c` extension, you should use `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` for it.

And in most cases you should specify needed include search paths in `CMakeLists.txt` itself:

```
include_directories(..)
```

Comment: Right. I was confused, because I thought CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS was also always used for .m files (and then I figured CXX means anything C, which it does not).

Depending on circumstances, at least on OS X, sometimes cmake uses c++ for .m files and sometimes cc. Then in one case CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is used and in the other CMAKE_C_FLAGS.